# Scenekit ways to control buffers cleaning?

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

I am struggling with issue of displaying big amount of `SCNNode`s on iPad using SceneKit. Exceeding some arbitrary amount of nodes on a scene, SceneKit's pipeline just chokes and hangs main thread in infinite mutex wait lock (or something like this, I just saw this in debugger stack trace as a point where main thread is stuck).

I know that issue is too many draw calls issuing by the scene (as shown by debugging), and that it is recommended to use `flattenedClone` to reduce amount of nodes and thus amount of draw calls required to render a frame (and actually yes, flattening really does help and causes scene to render). But I cannot use this technique because I need nodes to be displayed as they should be touchable (via `hitTest`) and display some information related to this exact node. Also nodes could change it's appearance individually in reaction to user input. Handling hit detection and node modification seems too complicated with use of `flattenedClone`.

Eventually I came up with an idea: if SceneKit has troubles rendering too many nodes per frame, what if I split rendering into multiple frames? For example, first frame renders nodes №1-1k, second frame renders nodes 1k-2k on top of previous frame and so on. When full circle is completed, the frame is cleared and process repeated. Yes, it will reduce effective FPS and create some drawing artifacts when camera moves, but this is acceptable for my requirements.

To make it work, I need control when SceneKit clears color and depth buffers, so 
I could pass output of one frame as input to another and control whether frame should be cleared (btw, I checked `SCNTechnique` and I didn't find a way to implement that).

Is it possible using SceneKit API? Is it even possible at all? Maybe there are some other ways of reducing amount of drawing calls that do not require ruining `SCNode`'s hierarchy?